# Letting modifier keys act as toggles under X

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xorg, gui, xkb

Is there any way to let the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys behave as toggles under X?
I know how one could do it under CLI (for example, by doing [this](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html)) but found
no reference for doing so under X.

Please note that this is *not* a question on sticky keys, which can be enabled
by an accessibility option.

Comment: Depends on what you are toggling for that would make a difference of the process.

Comment: @Casey Couldn't it be like caps lock (whose ON/OFF states are irrespective of incoming keys or mouse actions)?

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented on the DE level AFAIK. KDE has the option to Lock Sticky Keys:

> With Lock Sticky Keys enabled:
>
> If you press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key twice then press the <kbd>F</kbd> key, the computer
>   interprets this as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Now if you
>   type a P, the computer interprets this
>   as the letter P (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). To
>   de-select the Shift key, press it
>   again.

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-workspace/kcontrol/kcmaccess/index.html

Comment: That's a good answer for KDE users, though it isn't for GNOME users like myself.

Answer (score 0):

Keys in X11 are remapped with xmodmap,
but there is no Control_Lock in /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h

If you have a few keys you could map Control to something like ISO_Next_Group_Lock
and define your keys in this group with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd>.

I found some info here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=75771

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using XKB compatibility component

1. Check the compatibility variant you are using

   ```
   $ setxkbmap -v -query
   Trying to build keymap using the following components:
   keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
   types:      complete
   compat:     complete
   symbols:    pc+us(altgr-intl)+us:2+inet(evdev)
   geometry:   pc(pc105)
   rules:      evdev
   model:      pc105
   layout:     us,us
   variant:    altgr-intl,

   $ more /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/complete 
   default xkb_compatibility "complete"  {
       include "basic"
       augment "iso9995"
       augment "mousekeys"
       augment "accessx(full)"
       augment "misc"
       augment "xfree86"
       augment "level5"
       augment "caps(caps_lock)"
   };
   ```
2. Modify `misc` file, the one which contains the needed modifiers interpretations

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/misc
   ```

   I have changed `Shift_L`, `Alt_L` & `Alt_R` action from `SetMods` to `LockMods`, added new `Shift_R`, `Control_L` & `Control_R` interpretation with `LockMods` and commented `//setMods.clearLocks` (not sure if it's needed). Here is the complete file:

   ```
   default partial xkb_compatibility "misc"  {

       virtual_modifiers   Alt,Meta,Super,Hyper,ScrollLock;

       // Interpretations for some other useful keys

       interpret Terminate_Server {
           action = Terminate();
       };

       //setMods.clearLocks= True;

       // Sets the "Alt" virtual modifier

       interpret Alt_L+Any     {
           //useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Alt;
       action = LockMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Alt_L {
       action = LockMods(modifiers=Alt);
       };

       interpret Alt_R+Any     {
           //useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Alt;
       action = LockMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Alt_R {
       action = LockMods(modifiers=Alt);
       };

       // Sets the "Meta" virtual modifier

       interpret Meta_L+Any     {
   //        useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Meta;
       action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Meta_L    {
       action = SetMods(modifiers=Meta);
       };

       interpret Meta_R+Any     {
           //useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Meta;
       action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Meta_R    {
       action = SetMods(modifiers=Meta);
       };

       // Sets the "Super" virtual modifier

       interpret Super_L+Any     {
   //        useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Super;
       action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Super_L   {
       action = SetMods(modifiers=Super);
       };

       interpret Super_R+Any     {
           //useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Super;
       action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Super_R   {
       action = SetMods(modifiers=Super);
       };

       // Sets the "Hyper" virtual modifier

       interpret Hyper_L+Any     {
   //        useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Hyper;
       action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Hyper_L   {
       action = SetMods(modifiers=Hyper);
       };

       interpret Hyper_R+Any     {
           //useModMapMods= level1;
       virtualModifier= Hyper;
       action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       interpret Hyper_R   {
       action = SetMods(modifiers=Hyper);
       };

       // Sets the "ScrollLock" virtual modifier and
       // makes it actually lock when pressed.  Sets
       // up a map for the scroll lock indicator.
       interpret Scroll_Lock+Any   {
       virtualModifier= ScrollLock;
       action = LockMods(modifiers=modMapMods);
       };

       include "ledscroll"

       include "misc(assign_shift_left_action)"
   };

   partial xkb_compatibility "assign_shift_left_action"  {
       // Because of the irrevertable modifier mapping in symbols/pc <LFSH> is 
       // getting bound to the Lock modifier when using 
       // symbols/shift(both_capslock), creating unwanted behaviour. 
       // This is a quirk, to circumvent the problem.
       interpret Shift_L {
           action = LockMods(modifiers = Shift);
       };

       interpret Shift_R {
           action = LockMods(modifiers = Shift);
       };

       interpret Control_L {
           action = LockMods(modifiers = Control);
       };

       interpret Control_R {
           action = LockMods(modifiers = Control);
       };

   };
   ```
3. Compile the change & update the initramfs images

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
   ```
4. Reboot

**References:**

- [Archlinux Wiki: X KeyBoard extension](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension)
- [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/xkb.pdf)
- [XKB Configuration Files](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/node5.html)