# Making one certain key STICKY and another one into TOGGLING key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

How do I make <kbd>Fn</kbd> key work like toggle and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> sticky?

Currently, I want these two specific keys but I prefer a general solution to the problem.

Comment: Isn't that the standard behaviour?

Comment: I need to hold Fn to get special functions on F1-F12 keys and I use special layout so Caps Lock has different function than normaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Changing <kbd>Fn</kbd> may not possible only if the its manufacturer added such option
  to BIOS.

  Why?
  Short answer: Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> alone does not send a scancode.
  Long answer: See [How do Fn keys work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270416/how-do-fn-keys-work)
- Stiky key for Caps lock alone (not full accessibility sticky modifiers)

  1. Change Caps lock key interpretation

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/caps
     ```

     Change `LockMods` action to `LatchMods`

     ```
     partial xkb_compatibility "caps_lock"  {
         // Keysym Caps_Lock locks Lock modifier.
         // With this, the keysym Caps_Lock can be used without binding the whole
         // key to a real modifier.
             // This is essential when you don't want to use caps lock on the first
             // level.
             // This should not have any compatibility issues when used together with
             // other layouts which don't utilize this capability.
         interpret Caps_Lock {
             action = LatchMods(modifiers = Lock);
         };
     };
     ```
  2. Compile the change & update the initramfs images

     ```
     sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
     sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
     ```
  3. Reboot

  Note, I still don't know how to make keyboard led follow the state.

  To make toggle for other modifiers (ex <kbd>Alt</kbd>) change their `SetMods` action to `LockMods`. Most virtual modifiers are handled in `compat/misc` file.

  For references see my answer to other similar question: [Letting modifier keys act as toggles under X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6618/letting-modifier-keys-act-as-toggles-under-x/587127#587127)