# Making a Lock Key with Xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap, shortcut-keys

How do I create a "lock" or "sticky" key in Xmodmap – such as Caps_Lock? Currently, I am using a dead-Greek key, but I would also like a key that locks my keyboard into Greek until I press it again.

Comment: I expect you are using AltGr (Right Alt) as you dead key / alternative key / 3rd level shift. Check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/587127/26246 but only change Alt_R key to lock its modifier.